# my sendtowhatsapp.js does not execute my form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I want to make a form that send to whatsapp, by clicking submit, it must opening new tab to web whatsapp or whatsapp app if opening in mobile phone, but does not working. in my code in <head only css, and other js & jquery before </body

Trying to put js & jquery inside <head but still not working, trying put the js inside html but still not working too.

I'm so confused of this, maybe you're guys here have a solution for this, thank you.

here is my form code

```
                                    <form>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="nama">Nama</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nama" name="nama" placeholder="Nama lengkap">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="nohp">Nomor whatsapp</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nohp" name="nohp" placeholder="+628xxxxxxxxx">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="datepicker-autoclose">Tanggal acara</label><br/>    
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tanggal" id="datepicker-autoclose" placeholder="Day, dd/mm/yyyy">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Lokasi acara</label><br />
                                            <select class="selectpicker" name="lokasi" id="region" data-width="100%" data-style="form-control btn-secondary">
                                            <option value="" disabled selected>pilih lokasi acara...</option>
                                            <option value="cianjur">Cianjur</option>
                                            <option value="bandung">Bandung</option>
                                        </select>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <!-- Cianjur Pricelists -->
                                        <div class="form-group cianjur package">
                                            <label>Jenis acara & detail pricelist</label><br />
                                            <select class="selectpicker" name="paket-cjr" id="cjrpackage" data-width="100%" data-style="form-control btn-secondary">
                                                <option value="" selected>pilih jenis acara...</option>
                                                <option value="cjr-engagement">Engagement</option>
                                                <option value="cjr-prewedding">Prewedding</option>
                                                <option value="cjr-wedding">Wedding</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- Cianjur Pricelists End --> 
                                        
                                        <!-- bdg Pricelists -->
                                        <div class="form-group bandung package">
                                            <label>Jenis acara & detail pricelist</label><br />
                                            <select class="selectpicker" name="paket-bdg" id="bdgpackage" data-width="100%" data-style="form-control btn-secondary">
                                                <option value="" selected>pilih jenis acara...</option>
                                                <option value="bdg-engagement">Engagement</option>
                                                <option value="bdg-prewedding">Prewedding</option>
                                                <option value="bdg-wedding">Wedding</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- bdg Pricelists End --> 
                                        
                                            <!-- cjr engagement -->
                                            <div class="form-group cjr-engagement dtl">
                                                <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="card bg-success p-3 text-left text-white w-75 mx-auto">
                                                    <label><strong>IDR 850.000</strong></label>
                                                </div>
                                            
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- end of cjr engagement -->
                                            
                                            <!-- cjr prewedding -->
                                            <div class="form-group cjr-prewedding dtl">
                                                <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="card bg-success p-3 text-left text-white w-75 mx-auto">
                                                        <label><strong>IDR 1.000.000</strong></label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- end of cjr prewedding -->
                                            
                                            <!-- cjr wedding -->
                                            <div class="form-group cjr-wedding dtl">
                                                <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="card bg-success p-3 text-left text-white w-75 mx-auto">
                                                        <label><strong>IDR 1.200.000</strong></label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- end of cjr wedding -->
                                        
                                        <!-- bdg engagement -->
                                            <div class="form-group bdg-engagement dtl">
                                                <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="card bg-success p-3 text-left text-white w-75 mx-auto">
                                                    <label><strong>IDR 950.000</strong></label>
                                                </div>
                                            
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- end of bdg engagement -->
                                            
                                            <!-- bdg prewedding -->
                                            <div class="form-group bdg-prewedding dtl">
                                                <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="card bg-success p-3 text-left text-white w-75 mx-auto">
                                                        <label><strong>IDR 1.100.000</strong></label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- end of bdg prewedding -->
                                            
                                            <!-- bdg wedding -->
                                            <div class="form-group bdg-wedding dtl">
                                                <div style="margin-top:10px;" class="card bg-success p-3 text-left text-white w-75 mx-auto">
                                                        <label><strong>IDR 1.300.000</strong></label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- end of bdg wedding -->
                                        
                                        <!-- add on cjr engagement -->
                                        <div class="form-group cjr-engagement dtl">
                                        <label>Opsi tambahan</label><br />
                                            <div style="margin-left:3px;" class="checkbox checkbox-success">
                                                <input id="videographer" value="Videographer 300K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="videographer"> Crew videographer (IDR 300K) </label>
                                                <br />
                                                <input id="drone" value="Drone 200K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="drone"> Drone footage (IDR 200K) </label>
                                                <br />
                                                <input id="sde" value="SDE 300K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="sde"> Same day edit (IDR 300K) </label>
                                                <br />
                                                <input id="clip" value="Clip 200K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="clip"> 3-5 Menit Clip Video (IDR 300K)</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- end of add on cjr engagement -->
                                        
                                        <!-- add on cjr prewedding -->
                                        <div class="form-group cjr-prewedding dtl">
                                        <label>Opsi tambahan</label><br />
                                            <div style="margin-left:3px;" class="checkbox checkbox-success">
                                                <input id="videographer" value="Videographer 300K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="videographer"> Crew videographer (IDR 300K) </label>
                                                <br />
                                                <input id="drone" value="Drone 200K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="drone"> Drone footage (IDR 200K) </label>
                                                <br />
                                                <input id="sde" value="SDE 300K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="sde"> Same day edit (IDR 300K) </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- end of add on cjr prewedding -->
                                        
                                        <!-- add on cjr wedding -->
                                        <div class="form-group cjr-wedding dtl">
                                        <label>Opsi tambahan</label><br />
                                            <div style="margin-left:3px;" class="checkbox checkbox-success">
                                                <input id="videographer" value="Videographer 300K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="videographer"> Crew videographer (IDR 300K) </label>
                                                <br />
                                                <input id="drone" value="Drone 200K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="drone"> Drone footage (IDR 200K) </label>
                                                <br />
                                                <input id="sde" value="SDE 300K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="sde"> Same day edit (IDR 300K) </label>
                                                <br />
                                                <input id="clip" value="Clip 200K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="clip"> 3-5 Menit Clip Video (IDR 300K)</label>
                                                <br />
                                                <input id="siraman" value="Siraman 300K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="siraman"> Siraman (IDR 300K)</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- end of add on cjr wedding -->
                                        
                                        <!-- add on bdg engagement -->
                                        <div class="form-group bdg-engagement dtl">
                                        <label>Opsi tambahan</label><br />
                                            <div style="margin-left:3px;" class="checkbox checkbox-success">
                                                <input id="videographer" value="Videographer 300K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="videographer"> Crew videographer (IDR 300K) </label>
                                                <br />
                                                <input id="drone" value="Drone 200K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="drone"> Drone footage (IDR 300K) </label>
                                                <br />
                                                <input id="sde" value="SDE 300K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="sde"> Same day edit (IDR 300K) </label>
                                                <br />
                                                <input id="clip" value="Clip 200K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="clip"> 3-5 Menit Clip Video (IDR 300K)</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- end of add on bdg engagement -->
                                        
                                        <!-- add on bdg prewedding -->
                                        <div class="form-group bdg-prewedding dtl">
                                        <label>Opsi tambahan</label><br />
                                            <div style="margin-left:3px;" class="checkbox checkbox-success">
                                                <input id="videographer" value="Videographer 300K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="videographer"> Crew videographer (IDR 300K) </label>
                                                <br />
                                                <input id="drone" value="Drone 200K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="drone"> Drone footage (IDR 300K) </label>
                                                <br />
                                                <input id="sde" value="SDE 300K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="sde"> Same day edit (IDR 300K) </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- end of add on bdg prewedding -->
                                        
                                        <!-- add on bdg wedding -->
                                        <div class="form-group bdg-wedding dtl">
                                        <label>Opsi tambahan</label><br />
                                            <div style="margin-left:3px;" class="checkbox checkbox-success">
                                                <input id="videographer" value="Videographer 300K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="videographer"> Crew videographer (IDR 300K) </label>
                                                <br />
                                                <input id="drone" value="Drone 300K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="drone"> Drone footage (IDR 300K) </label>
                                                <br />
                                                <input id="sde" value="SDE 300K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="sde"> Same day edit (IDR 300K) </label>
                                                <br />
                                                <input id="clip" value="Clip 200K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="clip"> 3-5 Menit Clip Video (IDR 300K)</label>
                                                <br />
                                                <input id="siraman" value="Siraman 300K" type="checkbox">
                                                <label for="siraman"> Siraman (IDR 300K)</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- end of add on bdg wedding -->
                                        
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div style="margin-left:3px;" class="checkbox checkbox-success">
                                                <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" alt="default" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" class="model_img img-responsive">
                                                <label for="checkbox1"> Saya menyetujui <strong>Syarat & Ketentuan</strong> </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn-lg btn-success btn-block waves-effect waves-light m-r-10">Kirim</button>
                                </form>
```

and this inside sendtowhatsapp.js that not working

```
$(document).on('submit','form', function(){
var input_blanter = document.getElementById('nama');

/* Whatsapp Settings */
var walink = 'https://web.whatsapp.com/send',
    phone = '6281222079788',
    header = 'Halo saya ingin gratis',

/* Smartphone Support */
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
var walink = 'whatsapp://send';
}

if("" != input_blanter.value){

 /* Call Input Form */
var input_nama = $("#nama").val(),
    input_nohp = $("#nohp").val(),
    input_tglacara = $("#datepicker-autoclose").val(),
    input_lokasiacara = $("#region :selected").text(),
    input_packagecjr = $("#cjrpackage :selected").text(),
    input_packagebdg = $("#bdgpackage :selected").text(),
    input_videographer = $("#videographer").val(),
    input_drone = $("#drone").val(),
    input_sde = $("#sde").val(),
    input_clip = $("#clip").val(),
    input_siraman = $("#siraman").val();

/* Final Whatsapp URL */
var blanter_whatsapp = walink + '?phone=' + phone + '&text=' + header + '%0A%0A' +
    '*Nama* : ' + input_nama + '%0A' +
    '*Tanggal acara* : ' + input_tglacara + '%0A' +
    '*Lokasi acara* : ' + input_lokasiacara + '%0A' +
    '*Jenis acara & paket* : ' + input_packagecjr + input_packagebdg + '%0A' +
    '*Tambahan lainnya* : ' + input_videographer + input_drone + input_sde + input_clip + input_siraman + '%0A' +

/* Whatsapp Window Open */
window.open(blanter_whatsapp,'_blank');
alert("Success");
} else {
alert("Failed");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the jquery submit method instead of the document event will resolve the issue:

Instead of:

```
$(document).on('submit','form', function(){
```

Use:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
```

If you want to prevent redirect of the form, use `return false` at the end of the JS Code block.

```
$("form").submit(function(){
  // Remaining code

return false; // to prevent redirect
});
```